# In Gmail how do I mark a message as not being Spam and Delete it?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

Often when I am looking at my spam folder, I see message that are not Spam but that I do not wish to keep now that I have read them.   If I hit “Not spam” the message is then put into my inbox where I have to delete it with a separate action.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to take 2 actions within Gmail. The email that you mark as "Not Spam" is moved from one place to the other, so taking another action means you *have* to move to the inbox to see the message again.

Thunderbird or other IMAP services might be able to take multiple actions, but I can't comment since I've never used those products.

Answer (score -3):

In 30 days they will be automatically deleted. There as also the delete forever button within the spam page.

Here is another approach:

1. Create a label called `tobedeleted`, or any other name you want to use.
2. When you see a message that you want to be deleted attach the `tobedeleted` label using the "move to" button.
3. If at some point you want to free space then delete all the messages with the `tobedeleted` label

Comment: "In 30 days they will be automatically deleted" not if I say they are not spam.

Comment: But you said you wanted to delete them.

Comment: AND mark then as not being spam